# Finding same values in different rows and different columns in one table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a big table with tens of columns and over 2 million rows.
Some of the values of different rows might be the same and duplicated in different columns and different rows in the same table. How can I find them?

Example: I need to FIND all the THIS. However I do not know which is the VALUE 'THIS'.

```
id  |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |  c4  |  c5  |  
----+------+------+------+------+------+-------  
1   | THIS |   x  |   y  |   z  | NULL |  
2   | NULL | THIS |   f  |   b  |   c  |
3   | NULL |   h  | NULL |   p  | THIS |
```

Once I have found them, I will need to merge them and move all the THIS into Column c1, replacing NULL.

Any good idea?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe I do not understand you. You want to say that all other values (like x, y, z, f, b, c, h, p in your example are unique across all columns and rows? If you are looking for a dabase specific solution please tag your question with the database you use.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Hi thanks.  A classical of a newbe.  Is MS SQL.

Comment: Pilosa, Correct. All other values are unique across columns and rows except those that I named in the example THIS that can be different or duplicates. They are all names, but I do not know which names and I do not know which names are duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really think of anything better than the dumb SQL:

```
update table set c1='THIS' where c2='THIS' or c3='THIS' or c4='THIS' or ...
```

presumably you can use an editor to generate the query quite quickly, then copy and paste into mysql, psql or whatever.

Comment: Thanks. But the value THIS is unknown. I used THIS to give a value to a potential duplicate value. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first part about finding the duplicate values can be done with the following query. Adapt it to the number of columns your table has:

```
select c
from (
  select c1 as c from t
  union all select c2 from t
  union all select c3 from t
  union all select c4 from t
  union all select c5 from t
) x
group by c
having count(*) > 1
```

Reusing the query above you can get in which lines each value is repeated. You don't mention which database you are using, so I'll give you a CTE query that works in PostgreSQL. Minor changes may be needed in other databases:

```
with
v as (
  select id, c1 as c from t
  union all select id, c2 from t
  union all select id, c3 from t
  union all select id, c4 from t
  union all select id, c5 from t
),
d as (
  select c
  from v
  group by c
  having count(*) > 1
)
select
  v.c, v.id
from d
join v on v.c = d.c
order by v.c, v.id
```

Comment: Thanks. But the table has over 200 columns. Any solution where I do not have to type them all in?

Comment: The Impaler. This appears to be working, but how can I find in which rows/ID they are so that I can then merge them?

Comment: Added extra info to identify the rows where values are repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can read column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and compose your SQL dynamically.

I use [The Impaler's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59277248/12372860) to get the duplicate values. If your SQL Server's version is 2017 or higher you may want to use `STRING_AGG` for more readable code instead of `SET @p = ISNULL(@p + '...', '') + ...`.

```
DECLARE
    @p1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @p2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @p1 = ISNULL(@p1 + ' AS duplicate FROM your_table UNION ALL SELECT ', '') + COLUMN_NAME,
    @p2 = ISNULL(@p2 + ', ', '') + COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN('id', 'c1')

SET @sql = '
    WITH duplicates AS (
        SELECT t.duplicate FROM (SELECT ' + @p1 + ' FROM your_table) t WHERE t.duplicate IS NOT NULL GROUP BY t.duplicate HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
    UPDATE your_table
        SET
            c1 = d.duplicate
        FROM
            your_table t
            INNER JOIN duplicates d
                ON t.c1 IS NULL
                AND d.duplicate IN(' + @p2 + ')'

EXEC(@sql)
```